# Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEItueAuk/libpython3.7m.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, dcos

I've installed [minidcos](https://minidcos.readthedocs.io/) using below command

```
curl --fail -L https://github.com/dcos/dcos-e2e/releases/download/2019.10.10.0/minidcos -o /usr/local/bin/minidcos && \
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/minidcos
```

when I try to find the version after install to check everything is working fine I get below error -

```
    $ sudo minidcos --version
    [21667] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEItueAuk/libpython3.7m.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /tmp/_MEItueAuk/libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
```

I've libc.so.6 in the required path

```
        $ ls /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libc
        libc-2.23.so
        libcap.so.2
        libcap.so.2.24
        libcgmanager.so.0
        libcgmanager.so.0.0.0
        libcidn-2.23.so
        libcidn.so.1
        libcom_err.so.2
        libcom_err.so.2.1
        libcrypt-2.23.so
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0
        libcryptsetup.so.4
        libcryptsetup.so.4.6.0
        libcrypt.so.1
        libc.so.6
```

Note: 
   Os details -

```
    $ lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
    Release:        16.04
    Codename:       xenial
```

python details -

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

You can fix this issue in two ways. First of all, check your GLIBC version by running this command:

```
ldd --version
```

Most likely your GLIBC version is less than `2.28`. Now you could either upgrade the OS, I would say try Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, or you could lower down the `minidcos` version. Here I would recommend using version `2019.06.19.0` which is compiled with the lower version of GLIBC.

Comment: Had the same issue with mitmproxy/mitmdump v7. Went down to v6.0.2 and it works with GLIBC 2.26. :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the installed docker-compose:

if you're in bash terminal:

```
$ rm $(which docker-compose)
```

Or in fish terminal:

```
> rm (which docker-compose)
```

Go to releases page of Docker Compose:

https://github.com/docker/compose/releases

Download the source code (I've download the `compose-2.2.3.tar.gz` file at the bottom of the list). Extract its content and make your own build:

```
cd $HOME/Downloads
tar -xvf compose-2.2.3.tar.gz
cd compose-2.2.3
make
```

The output `compose-2.2.3` of compilation proccess will be placed into a created directory `bin`. You can run the generated file to check if it's working:

```
bin/docker-compose version
```

I use to run docker-compose from my `$HOME/.local/bin` directory so I did:

```
mv bin/docker-compose $HOME/.local/bin/
docker-compose version
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from our Python bump. The official images only provide Debian Buster for 3.9 The former has glibc 2.28 while Ubuntu 18.04 only has 2.27.

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.27.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: I don't know how this is gonna fix my issue? my question is not at all related to docker-compose

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @RajkumarNatarajan

The issue comes from our Python bump. The official images only provide Debian Buster for 3.9. The former has glibc 2.28 while Ubuntu 18.04 only has 2.27.

Issue is with docker compose.

Please  try it out first.