# Executable made with Pyinstaller doens't work in another computer

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, debian, pyinstaller, linux-mint

I'm pretty new in python programming and I made a program using Tkinter that do some calculations with  some info that I take from Xml files.

So the problem is that I have to export this program to run in another computer and I'm building with the Pyinstaller, but it doens't work. When I try to run the program in the other computer I get the error

```
Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIoYBzG0/libpython3.9.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIoYBzG0/libpython3.9.so.1.0)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.. I'm using a Linux Mint with Python 3.9.18 and Pyinstaller 6.0.0 to build the program and the other computer is a Debian 5.10 with Python 3.9.2.

I'm using Pycharm do program and this command to build a executable.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --debug=all xlmlminidom.py
```

I tried to change the version of Python (I was using the Python 3.10) and it didn't work. And I installed the `libc6` in the computer but still not working.

I have to install Tkinter in the other computer?

Thank you.

Comment: If packaged correctly the other computer doesn't need anything to be installed, not even python....is [this helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483026/error-loading-python-lib-tmp-meitueauk-libpython3-7m-so-1-0-dlopen-lib-x8)

Comment: Looking at the other computer I saw that it has an old version from Glibc (2.31), in my computer I have the 2.35 version... I read in some sites that I cannot upgrade only the Glibc. So I'm trying to understand how I can containerize the app.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that Python fails to load the shared library libpython3.9.so.1.0, because the system GLIBC version is too old and doesn't meet the minimum requirement of Python build. Here are some possible solutions:

**1.Upgrade the system glibc version, usually by doing a system update.**

**2.Recompile and reinstall Python from source, linking against the needed glibc version.**

**3.If system update is not possible, download the required glibc version and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to it so that Python loads the specific glibc version.**

**4.Use Docker or other container technologies to run Linux and Python in containers with specific versions to avoid compatibility issues with host.**

**5.Check Python release notes for glibc requirements and choose a Linux distro that meets the needs to install Python.**

And as what Rory in comments said: *"If packaged correctly the other computer doesn't need anything to be installed, not even python"*

Hope this will help you.